# Where do I find aux files in Overleaf?

Tags: auxiliary-files, overleaf

Currently I am working in a template on Overleaf. I decided I wanted to use a different citation style, so I turned this:

```
\bibliography{report}
```

into this:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{report}
```

That gave the following warning:

```
./report.tex:
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [largelogo].
(no line number):
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: report.aux
The style file: my-report.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 46 of file report.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {ieeetr}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: report.bib
You've used 5 entries,
            2773 wiz_defined-function locations,
            635 strings with 6341 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 2901 in all, are:
= -- 265
> -- 195
< -- 2
+ -- 65
```

Now it seems the template already defines a citation style. The programmer in me now wants to go to line 46 in `report.aux` to look what happens there.

However there is no such file in my entire project. According to [this](https://www.overleaf.com/help/207-how-do-i-download-the-automatically-generated-files-e-dot-g-bbl-aux-ind-gls-for-my-project-my-publisher-asked-me-to-include-them-in-my-submission#.WaRQMRdLdhF) FAQ answer on Overleaf, I need to download an extensive zip-version of the project to see these files. However when I do that, the zip-file again doesn't contain a report.aux file.

So my question is: does this file exist (at any point)? If yes, where do I find this file? If not, where does the warning refer to?

Note: in this question I am not directly interested in the original problem, but specifically in the `report.aux` file referenced in the warning.

Comment: note.there seems to be some beta program with better UI or something https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594523/250119

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update for Overleaf version 2: the menu has changed.

If you need any additional files, you can find them in the compiler panel under "Logs and output files" and "other logs & files".

[image]

Answer (score 6):

*This post is valid only for Overleaf version 1 (I do not know if it is still used). For Overleaf v2, see the other answer.*

As far as I know, the only way to get all the auxliary files is to select 
`Project` (if not already displayed) and then `DOWNLOAD AS ZIP --> Input and Output Files`.

In this way you can download a `.zip` with all your auxilary files.

Note that you have to use `Input and Output Files`, not `Input Files Only`, which is the default if you only click on `DOWNLOAD AS ZIP`.

[image]