# Generate bbl from bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I have a project on Overleaf and I am using `bibtex` for managing my references. This has a `.bib` file. I want to put the paper on arxiv and they want me to add a `.bbl` file not `.bib`. How can I convert `.bib` to `.bbl` ?

Comment: The bbl file is generated by BibTeX. Have you been running BibTeX?

Comment: You can download it from Overleaf (it is already generated automatically), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456099/.

Comment: You can also publish to arXiv directlt from Overleaf, see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Exporting_your_work_from_Overleaf#Downloading_with_.bbl_file.2C_for_journal_submission

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864