# Overleaf dynamic PDF filenames

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, latexmk, jobname

I have an Overleaf project that contains multiple `.tex` files to create different PDF documents.
If I compile one of the `.tex` files and download it, it is named after the Overleaf project.
Currently, if I want the PDF file to have the same name as the corresponding `.tex` file, I have to rename the PDF file after downloading.
Is there a way to make Overleaf change the PDF filenames to the names of the `.tex` files they are created from?
Say, I have `doc1.tex` and `doc2.tex`.
My goal is that when I download the PDF file for `doc1.tex` the PDF file is named `doc1.pdf` and when I download the PDF file for `doc2.tex` the filename is `doc2.pdf`.

My approach is to create a custom `latexmkrc` file.
When I add the following line to Overleaf's [default `latexmkrc` file](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F), the compilation works.

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -shell-escape -file-line-error --synctex=-1 %O %S ';
```

But appending `-jobname=newfilename` to this line does not change the name of the PDF file when I download it.

What is the problem here or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think that is a question better asked at Overleaf Support than here.

Comment: remark, regarding how to download non-main PDF refer to [Where do I find aux files in Overleaf? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388656/where-do-i-find-aux-files-in-overleaf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

If your different TeX files are called e.g. `first.tex` and `second.tex`, you can achieve having `first.pdf` amongst the output files so that when you download it, it will be called this way. Note that this is unfortunately not really straightforward; we didn't really intend a single project to be used that way with a lot of downloading of the PDFs for different documents within the project.

Anyway, to achieve the above, you can make a file called e.g. `make_first.tex` with contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc,pdfpages}
\ShellEscape{latexmk -pdf first}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{first.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If needed, you can switch `-pdf` to `-lualatex` or `-xelatex` to change the compiler. You can have a similar setup for any of the documents within the project.

However, `first.pdf` is only shown among the "Logs and Output Files" in the current UI. If you want to reach them better you can opt in for our Beta Program to get a new UI that's currently being finalized and that makes it easier to reach the output files. (This is current as of April 2021.)

Comment: Neat trick, Pasting the lines `\ShellEscape{latexmk -pdf first}` and `\includepdf[pages=-]{first.pdf}` multiple times for different `.tex` files even one "make" file is sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to right click on the "download" button (it is to the right of compile) and choose the name of where to save it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my browser (Firefox 98.0.1) I need to right-click the download button and select `Save Link As...` to open the desired save-file dialog. Maybe a screenshot or mentioning which item to select in the right-click context menu could improve your answer.